# Default Sort Order in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an Interactive Grid, and I would like the grid to show the latest date records on top. However, Interactive Grid doesn't support Order by in the SQL.

Is there any way I can have these sorts applied by default, instead of user need to sort these reports by himself?

Also, I don't want to use Save Report as a developer as there are more than 400 reports in our application. Is there a programmable way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Manually, you can:**

- Open the Oracle APEX Builder and make sure you are logged in as developer
- Run the Page with the Interactive Grid in the browser and log in with the same credentials
- Apply an order by on one (or more) of the columns
- Click 'Actions' -> 'Report'-> 'Save'
- You should see the confirmation "Default report saved for all users"

**Programmatically, you can't:**

In APEX 20.1 there is a PL/SQL API available, [APEX_IG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/APEX_IG.html#GUID-9A4189AF-FEAE-4CC0-A602-A10A5E4868C2). But currently it doesn't contain functionality what you're looking for..

New functionality will probably be added in future versions of APEX, but that's a guess and surely not something you can use right now.

Comment: Not a limitation. But a lot of repetitive work would be needed to implement this. I was wondering whether there is a programmable way to implement this, say by calling a JavaScript function or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `WITH` clause to "hide" `ORDER BY` clause from IG.

Let's say your select is:

`select emp_id, name, date from employees`

and you want to use `order by` clause in interactive grid's SQL, you just copy it into this:

```
 WITH my_sel AS 
  (SELECT emp_id, name, date 
     FROM employees
   ORDER BY date DESC)

SELECT emp_id, name, date
  FROM my_sel;
```

You can find more examples [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql99_with_clause.htm).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but if you do this, APEX will think it's a view and won't allow delete actions.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by column:

```
01. Click the Actions menu, select Data, then Sort. The Sort dialog appears.

02. In the Sort dialog: Select a column, the sort direction (Ascending or Descending), and the null sorting behavior (Default, Nulls Always Last, or Nulls Always First).
    a. Column - Select a column.
    b. Direction - Select Descending or Ascending.
    c. Nulls - Select First or Last.
03. To add another sort rule, click the Add button (+).
04. Click Save.

05. Click Report
06. Click Save
```

The interactive grid reloads.

Note: To ensure that you are login developer mode, otherwise it is not show other user